# Magic Mouse scrolling stops working after horizontal scrolling

Tags: macos, scroll, horizontal-scrolling, magic-mouse

Occasionally when I scroll horizontally in an app using the magic mouse, the current tab or page I'm scrolling on freezes and thereon in that app, scrolling is completely non-functional.

For example, if I'm using Safari and I scroll horizontally to go back to the previous link, the current tab freezes, stuck in the middle of the animation. If I close the frozen tab, the other tabs work fine, but I can't scroll vertically or horizontally in them. I have to scroll using the scrollbar. No other apps are affected and if I restart the affected application, everything goes back to normal and the mouse scrolling is functional again.

Has anybody else had this issue? Any ideas on how to fix this?

I was running Lion when this issue started. I updated to Mavericks hoping it would be fixed, but no luck. I'm currently running Mavericks GM on an iMac (latest model).

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue after installing Mavericks. Go to System Preferences/General and click on Show scroll bars: Check "Always". Hope this helps.